# Magento - query to get active categories in current store

Tags: mysql, magento

I would like to issue to a SQL query to retrieve the active categories from my magento store. I am currently issuing the following query, but its returning the non active categories as well:-

> SELECT entity_id, name, url_path FROM catalog_category_flat_store_1
>   WHERE level >=3 ORDER BY catalog_category_flat_store_1.parent_id ASC,
>   catalog_category_flat_store_1.position ASC

Comment: Why do you want to run raw sql queries instead of using product collections?

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something here, but have you tried limiting by `is_active` in your query?

```
select entity_id, name, url_path
  from catalog_category_flat_store_1
  where level >= 3 and
        is_active = 1
  order by parent_id asc, position asc;
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your response. I actually did try that query but it doesnt seem to fetch the active categories. Since i am short of time, i ended up sending an http request to the url and checking the headers for a 200 OK to make sure that I'm working with a proper category url. It is time consuming and impractical but i was left with no choice.

Comment: Ow, that hurts. You should probably circle back around and fix that sooner than later :)